# Azure Monitor Data Collector API Powershell sample doesn't work

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I tried to use the PowerShell sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api#powershell-sample without any changes.

It completes with status **200** (OK) and correctly creates a new table with LogType (MyRecordType) within the **Custom Logs** in the portal (Log Analytics Workspace->Logs).

However, the events that are submitted don't turn up there - there are always "No results from the last 24 hours". Also, within the new table, none of the custom properties are created.

Has anybody observed a similar problem? (Some people seem to be using the C# code successfully.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Crazy... on the next day, all the events had turned up in the Log Analytics workspace. Even new events that I generated turned up immediately.

It seems this was a glitch just on that day. Well, the API is in "preview"...